# Slf4j - enable debug,info messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

I need to enable debug,info logs in a existing Java/spring-boot project.

This is the original application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.io.comp=INFO
```

and this is the original logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property name="LOGS_PATH" value="./logs" />

<appender name="ERROR_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}_error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}_error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="DEBUG_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}_debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}_debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="INFO_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="DUMP_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}_dump.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}_dump.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- Loggers -->
<logger name="io.comp" additivity="true">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LOG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
</logger>


<!-- Root Logger -->
<root level="DEBUG" >
    <appender-ref ref="DUMP_LOG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
</root>

<root level="INFO" >
    <appender-ref ref="INFO_LOG_FILE" />
</root>
```

i tried to change the application.properties file to:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.io.comp=DEBUG
```

and the logback.xml file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property name="LOGS_PATH" value="./logs" />

<appender name="ERROR_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}_error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}_error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="DEBUG_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}_debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}_debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="INFO_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="DUMP_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS_PATH}/${NODE_NAME}_dump.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread][%-5level][%logger{0}] %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/archived/${NODE_NAME}_dump.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- Loggers -->
<logger name="io.comp" additivity="true">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LOG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="INFO_LOG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
</logger>


<!-- Root Logger -->
<root level="DEBUG" >
    <appender-ref ref="DUMP_LOG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LOG_FILE" />
</root>

<root level="INFO" >
    <appender-ref ref="INFO_LOG_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LOG_FILE" />
</root>
```

but with no success. Only logs with levels: error,warn (log.error, log.warn) are printed to the the files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

Within the configuration of the project, reference was made to another properties file, in which the Logger level was WARN.